# Is it possible to write this code without dot notation?

Tags: objective-c

The title says it all. Is it possible to write this code without using the "." notation?

```
    if ([aTableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"code"]){
    some code here
    }
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure

```
[aTableColumn identifier]
```

so

```
if ([[aTableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"code"]){
    some code here
}
```

dot syntax is just syntactic sugar and NEVER mandatory for objC calls